# Efficient JSON parsing with php

Tags: php, json

I have a web app that uses php to scan a lot of last.fm JSON data.  Here is the php that I currently use to parse it.

```
<?php
$lfm = file_get_contents('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettopartists&api_key=apikey&format=json');
$json = json_decode($lfm, true);
foreach ($json['artists']['artist'] as $track) {
    $artist = $track['name'];
    $image = $track['image'][2]['#text'];
    if ($artist&&$image){
        echo 'data';
    }
}
?>
```

The php that I currently use does the job, but it seems to be very slow at times.  I was wondering if there were a more efficient way to write this code that would make it perform better, or if it is just slow because I am running it through such large amounts of data.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The JSON decoding won't be the slow part; fetching the JSON from the API will be far, far, far slower.

Comment: No, the fastest way to decode json is to decode json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most likely **not** due to your code, but rather that it takes a while to download the external JSON.

You should consider caching it.

### Finding where the problem lies

You can check where the problem lies, by using `microtime()`:

```
<?php
    $timeStart = microtime(true);
    $lfm = file_get_contents('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettopartists&api_key=apikey&format=json');
    $timeAfterGet = microtime(true);
    $json = json_decode($lfm, true);
    foreach ($json['artists']['artist'] as $track) {
        $artist = $track['name'];
        $image = $track['image'][2]['#text'];
        if ($artist&&$image){
            echo 'data';
        }
    }
    $timeEnd = microtime(true);
    echo "Time taken to get JSON: " . number_format($timeAfterGet - $timeStart, 4) . " seconds<br />";
    echo "Time taken to go through JSON: " . number_format($timeEnd - $timeAfterGet, 4) . " seconds<br />";
?>
```

### Caching

Keep a local file - check when the file was last modified and if it's less than `MAX_CACHE_LIFETIME` (in seconds), then use the cached file.

```
<?php
    define("MAX_CACHE_LIFETIME", 60 * 60); //1 hour

    $localJSONCache = "audioscrobbler.json.cache";

    $lfm = null;
    if (file_exists($localJSONCache)) {
        if (time() - filemtime($localJSONCache) < MAX_CACHE_LIFETIME) {
            $lfm = file_get_contents($localJSONCache);
        }
    }
    if (empty($lfm)) {
        $lfm = file_get_contents('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettopartists&api_key=apikey&format=json');
        file_put_contents($localJSONCache, $lfm);
    }
    $json = json_decode($lfm, true);
    foreach ($json['artists']['artist'] as $track) {
        $artist = $track['name'];
        $image = $track['image'][2]['#text'];
        if ($artist&&$image){
            echo 'data';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: How would I go about caching the external JSON since it is not hosted on my website.  Any help would be appreciated, and thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Eggo I've updated the answer with a simple cache solution (note that whenever something comes from the cache, it will not download the newest version)

Comment: This has definitely made a huge improvement in load time.  Thank you so much for the help!  I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @Eggo Glad I could help - keep in mind that I forgot to create the cache file - I've added it now: `file_put_contents($localJSONCache, $lfm);`.